# samsung 300epx a0j brightness doesn not work

Tags: ubuntu, debian

hi all in this my laptop i cat change brightness setting in kde or gnome, after press setting keys on keyboard screen looping low and high brightness and not working

```
tux-world@alachiq ~ $  lspci | grep VGA
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 09)

tux-world@alachiq ~ $ xrandr --output LVDS --set BACKLIGHT 102 --set BACKLIGHT_CONTROL legacy --output VGA --auto
warning: output LVDS not found; ignoring
warning: output VGA not found; ignoring
X Error of failed request:  BadRROutput (invalid Output parameter)
  Major opcode of failed request:  150 (RANDR)
  Minor opcode of failed request:  15 (RRGetOutputProperty)
  Serial number of failed request:  30
  Current serial number in output stream:  30
```

this command dont return any result:

```
tux-world@alachiq ~ $ xbacklight -inc 10
```

all setting in kde brightness is 100%